# Account missing in account association

Tags: bug, status-completed, linked-accounts

I have accounts on 14 sites: webapps, webmaster, gadget, photo, tex, ubuntu, unix, apple + SF, SU, SO, MSO, A51, stackapps.

Looking at my profile on any site, [on SF for example](https://serverfault.com/users/9503?tab=accounts#tab-top),  apple and unix are missing.
I can understand that Apple is missing as it's in private beta, but Unix is in public beta. Why doesn't it appear? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed; some bits were not flipped in the site metadata.

Comment: Hum, I still don't see the unix site, caching issue may be ? I will look again later

Comment: It's now working :)