# LEGO® Answers account is missing in account directory

Tags: bug, status-completed

According to **[Account missing in account association](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61725/162993)** it looks like some "bits need to be flipped" to show the LEGO® Answers account in my (er, looks like everybody's) Accounts profile.

In my [accounts profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/719186/larstech?tab=accounts), the LEGO® Answers account should be showing up between UX and Programmers.

The summary at the top of the listing says **35 Accounts**, but only 34 appear in the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, yeah, that was problem #183 or so created by that damn little R.  It should be all better now.

Comment: Well, you can blame the powers that be for that.  It *was* suggested the site be called [Brick Overflow](http://meta.bricks.stackexchange.com/a/84/175), but it was rejected.  Could have saved you 183+ problems.

Comment: However now we've got the name I for one am quite happy with it ;)

Comment: @LarsTech But just think, if they ever need to include an ® or a © in another site's name, they won't have these problems again ;)

Comment: Bricks.SE doesn't appear on my list of accounts on Area 51 either. http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/32727?tab=accounts