# LEGO® Answers account is missing in summary page

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-accounts

Last week I posted [LEGO® Answers account is missing in account directory](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122621/162993) and Nick Craver promptly fixed it:

> So, yeah, that was problem #183 or so created by that damn little R. It should be all better now.

I noticed today that problem #184 showed up in the summary page:

[image]

This is from one of the moderators of the LEGO® Answers site: [Ambo100 Moderator](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/users/132/ambo100).

Comment: And it's back :) Yay for devs! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We'll reconcile what this list displays versus your actual accounts and users very soon.

Update: this is fixed.

Comment: This is also the case on the mobile view of the site, see [my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123372/33051) for details.

Comment: If only I could get my own developers to fix bugs this fast.  Kudos.

Answer (score 0):

When viewing the accounts page for any user on [LEGO Answers](http://bricks.stackexchange.com) on the mobile site I can't see their LEGO Answers account details, regardless of which site I view it from.

The heading lists the correct number of accounts, in my case 16 but then doesn't display them all, it only lists 15. In many of the cases I've looked at the LA site should be the second or third on the list.

Further information:

- This appears to be happening on the mobile view (Safari on iPhone) - switching to full site shows the account
- I'm a mod on LA.SE

Some examples:

- [Me on LA.SE](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/users/56/zhaph-ben-duguid?tab=accounts)
- [Joubarc on LA.SE](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/users/99/joubarc?tab=accounts)
- [PCantin on SO](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/users/99/joubarc?tab=accounts)